# Creating a simple DApp

Tags: dapps, ipfs

I want to implement the `"Decentrilized Gallery"`, and implement it to the blockchain(ethereum) and it's kinda will work like:

> Basic html page with a button in the middle to choose a picture from
>   local computer, after that that picture is going to be "live" on
>   IPFS. I know how to do that, using as a source of picture the URL
>   link(there is a lot of tutorials about it), but i want to try to
>   upload from local host and through UI(my button) and not through web
>   page console(tutorials do).

Who could tell me, what basics steps should i take, or direct me in the right direction. Or at least, is it possible at all or make scence, would listen any advices and critics ))

```
<!doctype>
<html>

<div class="upload">   
     <input type="file" class="file-input">    
    <input type="button" value="Browse">    
    <span class="filename">No file selected</span>  
  </div>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="storage/web.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ipfs/ipfs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /* Configuration variables */
    var ipfsHost    = 'localhost';
    var ipfsAPIPort = '5001';
    var ipfsWebPort = '8080';
    var web3Host    = 'http://localhost';
    var web3Port    = '8545';

    /* IPFS initialization */
    var ipfs = window.IpfsApi(ipfsHost, ipfsAPIPort)
    ipfs.swarm.peers(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            var numPeers = res.Peers === null ? 0 : res.Peers.length;
            console.log("IPFS - connected to " + numPeers + " peers");
        }
    });

    /* web3 initialization */
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(web3Host + ':' + web3Port));
    if (!web3.isConnected()) {
        console.error("Ethereum - no connection to RPC server");
    } else {
        console.log("Ethereum - connected to RPC server");
    }

    /* JavaScript smart contract interface */
    var contractInterface = [{
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [{
            "name": "x",
            "type": "string"
        }],
        "name": "set",
        "outputs": [],
        "type": "function"
    }, {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "get",
        "outputs": [{
            "name": "x",
            "type": "string"
        }],
        "type": "function"
    }];

    var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];

    var contractObject = {
        from: account,
        gas: 300000,
        data: '0x6060604052610282806100126000396000f360606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900480634ed3885e146100445780636d4ce63c1461009a57610042565b005b6100986004808035906020019082018035906020019191908080601f016020809104026020016040519081016040528093929190818152602001838380828437820191505050505050909091905050610115565b005b6100a760048050506101c6565b60405180806020018281038252838181518152602001915080519060200190808383829060006004602084601f0104600f02600301f150905090810190601f1680156101075780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b509250505060405180910390f35b8060006000509080519060200190828054600181600116156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f016020900481019282601f1061016457805160ff1916838001178555610195565b82800160010185558215610195579182015b82811115610194578251826000505591602001919060010190610176565b5b5090506101c091906101a2565b808211156101bc57600081815060009055506001016101a2565b5090565b50505b50565b602060405190810160405280600081526020015060006000508054600181600116156101000203166002900480601f0160208091040260200160405190810160405280929190818152602001828054600181600116156101000203166002900480156102735780601f1061024857610100808354040283529160200191610273565b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060200180831161025657829003601f168201915b5050505050905061027f565b9056'
    };

    var sendDataObject = {
        from: account,
        gas: 300000,
    };

    window.ipfs = ipfs;
    window.web3 = web3;
    window.account = account;
    window.contractObject = contractObject;
    window.contract = web3.eth.contract(contractInterface);
    window.ipfsAddress = "http://" + ipfsHost + ':' + ipfsWebPort + "/ipfs";

    function deployStorage() {
        window.IPFSHash = null;
        window.currentData = null;

        if (window.contractInstance) {
            console.error('Contract already been deployed at: ', window.contractAddress);
            return;
        }

        window.contract.new(window.contractObject, function (err, contract) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Contract deployment error: ", err);
            } else if (contract.address) {
                window.contractAddress = contract.address;
                window.contractInstance = window.contract.at(contract.address);
                console.log("Contract successfully deployed at: ", contract.address);
            } else if (contract.transactionHash) {
                console.log("Awaiting contract deployment with transaction hash: ", contract.transactionHash);
            } else {
                console.error("Unresolved contract deployment error");
            }
        });
    }

    function storeContent(url) {
        window.ipfs.add(url, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Content submission error:", err);
                return false;
            } else if (result && result[0] && result[0].Hash) {
                console.log("Content successfully stored. IPFS address:", result[0].Hash);
            } else {
                console.error("Unresolved content submission error");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    function storeAddress(data) {
        if (!window.contractInstance) {
            console.error('Ensure the storage contract has been deployed');
            return;
        }

        if (window.currentData == data) {
            console.error("Overriding existing data with same data");
            return;
        }

        window.contractInstance.set.sendTransaction(data, window.sendDataObject, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Transaction submission error:", err);
            } else {
                window.currentData = data;
                console.log("Address successfully stored. Transaction hash:", result);
            }
        });
    }

    function fetchContent() {
        if (!window.contractInstance) {
            console.error("Storage contract has not been deployed");
            return;
        }

        window.contractInstance.get.call(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Content fetch error:", err);
            } else if (result && window.IPFSHash == result) {
                console.log("New data is not mined yet. Current data: ", result);
                return;
            } else if (result) {
                window.IPFSHash = result;
                var URL = window.ipfsAddress + "/" + result;
                console.log("Content successfully retrieved. IPFS address", result);
                console.log("Content URL:", URL);
            } else {
                console.error('No data, verify the transaction has been mined');
            }
        });
    }

    function getBalance() {
        window.web3.eth.getBalance(window.account, function (err, balance) {
            console.log(parseFloat(window.web3.fromWei(balance, "ether")));
        });
    }

    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all I built a few dapps containing a IPFS image upload component, generally speaking the concept is very simple.

All you need to do create a relatively simple smart contract to store the ipfs hash (unique identifer). And you can access the image via https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/IPFSHASH. It seems that you have the right idea using the javascript interface, but I think you want a full on dapp for this. Recommend using drizzle-box as a starting point..

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Contract {
 string ipfsHash;
 mapping (address => string[]) userToFiles;
 event (string ipfsHash, address owner) filesUploaded;

 function setHash(string x) public {
   ipfsHash = x;
   // update files 
   // update array
 }

 function getHash() public view returns (string x) {
   return ipfsHash;
 }
}
```

Of course in your case you will need some way to view all if not part of the images returned.

Disclaimer this is the smart contract I built myself, I do not guarantee security or anything else, also this doesn't work in solidity V0.5.0.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
/// @author David Li
/// @notice Stores a filelist on solidity, since an array of structs cannot easily be returned
/// the structs must be decomposed on the front-end
/// @dev simple filelist contains ipfshash, filename, owner, tags and unix timestamp
/// @dev one way to create a "trello" like application would require creating more modifiers and perhaps
/// role based access control.
/// @dev since I can't use an bytes32 array in solidity, I decided to have tag numbers
/// corresponding to string names, almost like a dictionary look up.
contract FileList {

   /// @dev struct that contains unique link to image (via IPFS), serial Id, and timestamp
   struct File {
      uint256 id;
      string ipfshash;
      bytes32 filename;
      bytes32[5] tags;
      address owner;
      uint256 timestamp;
   }
   uint256 public constant maxAmountOfFiles = 1000;
   // Owner => files
   mapping(address => File[maxAmountOfFiles]) public files;
   // Owner => last files id
   mapping(address => uint256) public lastIds;
   // consider mapping hash to set of tags

   /// @dev main event for smart contract, needed for drizzle to update list of files
   event fileAdded (uint256 fileid, string ipfshash, bytes32 _filename);
   event tagsAdded (bytes32[5] tags);

   /// @dev Add a file to the list
   /// @param ipfshash an ipfshash returned after an image is finished uploaded
   /// @param _filename name of file as a bytes32 as filenames should be short
   /// @param tags array of bytes32 used for sorting/searching files (e,g. blockchain, school, textbook)
   /// @notice updates mappings todos and lastIds
   function addFile(string ipfshash, bytes32 _filename, bytes32[5] tags) public {

      File memory myFile = File(lastIds[msg.sender], ipfshash, _filename, tags,  msg.sender, now);
      // explicitly store tags
      myFile.tags = tags;
      emit tagsAdded (myFile.tags);
      // store new file in mapping

      files[msg.sender][lastIds[msg.sender]] = myFile;
      // emit event, also need for drizzle
      emit fileAdded(lastIds[msg.sender],ipfshash,_filename);
      if(lastIds[msg.sender] >= maxAmountOfFiles) lastIds[msg.sender] = 0;
      else lastIds[msg.sender]++;
   }

   /// @dev return the tags for a specific file 
   /// @param owner --- address of person who uploaded the file 
   /// @param _index --- the file desired, (first file uploaded, second , etc ...)
   function getFileTags(address owner, uint256 _index) external view returns (bytes32[5]) {
       return files[owner][_index].tags;
  }

}
```

and I load data using some chained promises [chained promises](https://github.com/FriendlyUser/file-track-Dapp/blob/730fc93b7cd3c0167933c18e9eb84ce01f99749d/src/components/FileTable.js#L44).

I remember following this tutorial a week after it was released [IPFS and React](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/hands-on-get-started-with-infura-and-ipfs-on-ethereum-b63635142af0?gi=1034836e4062)

For example you can see a simple dapp I built, [Ipfs-Dapp](http://ipfsdapp.surge.sh/) for storing images on the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

While it might not teach you how to specifically making a you DApp, it will give you the tools to make one yourself, which is probably better! When learning I found this to be the most encompassing tutorial that explained most aspects of the project from start to finish

https://coursetro.com/courses/20/Developing-Ethereum-Smart-Contracts-for-Beginners